# Is there a way using Javascript to redirect users back to an original destination once they've logged in?

Tags: javascript, json

Ok so here's what's currently in place...

1. Users navigate to WEBSITE#1
2. The following script is in place in the `<head>` section which redirects users to WEBSITE#2 to login and authenticate:

   ```
   <script>
   function processJSON (json) 
   { 
      if ( json.Auth != 'OK' ) 
      { 
        window.location.replace("WEBSITE#2/login.php"); 
      } 
   };
   </script>
   <script src='WEBSITE#2/CheckAuth.php?jsoncallback=processJSON'>
   </script>
   ```
3. Once logged in, it then opens the homepage of WEBSITE#2.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to add further script to redirect users back to WEBSITE#1 after authentication instead of taking them to the homepage of WEBSITE#2.

I hope this all makes sense, any help here would be MASSIVELY appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you create the WEBSITE#2 on your own? Then you can just redirect from there to WEBSITE#1 as you do it from #2 to #1

Comment: Hi Mario, thanks for your rapid reply. No, WEBSITE#2 was made and is maintained by a third party developer (who I can send requests to easily). Just to explain a little further... WEBSITE#2 is a portal which needs to be accessed as a standalone site if users want to log in and use it, and not always be redirected back to WEBSITE#1. The reason the Javascript is there in the first place is to protect public access by forcing the user to log in on WEBSITE#2. So this code would need to redirect users back to WEBSITE#1 only if they are trying to reach that site initially - if that makes sense...

Comment: Alright, but this should actually be the part of the owner of WEBSITE#2 - he should provide such a solution that the user can be redirected ...

Comment: Ok, thank you Mario. Only trouble is, I'm fairly sure he doesn't know Javascript... (don't ask!) Just to be clear I'm not trying to avoid hiring a developer to find a solution, I was just being optimistic and hoping there would be a small bit of code available to make this happen!

Comment: Uh, then this could be hard :(

Comment: I had a feeling it could be... thanks again anyway for jumping on my Q so fast.

Comment: You're welcome - but do you think you can touch his code?

Comment: Not directly - but I can send requests for him to update accordingly. I'm going to drop a message to him now and will come back and update this Q once I've received a response.

Comment: Alright :) actually it will be necessary that he does something on this side

Comment: I've been advised the following: "It’s a really bad idea to do that sort of thing. You’ll find you end up with some uncontrollable redirecting, especially if one is going back to the other. You could end up in an infinite redirect to each other. The real problem you have is that you are trying to authenticate across different domains. The only way you can really do it is via a cookie hack." With this in mind, I feel as though what I'm trying to do isn't worth the hassle...

Comment: Oh okay ... well yes sounds like a greater change